# Formatting a table output from php code

Tags: php, html, joomla

I have written the following code, but somehow the headers are not matching the generated columns in the rendered table,, can someone give me a hint on how to improve it?

```
    <?php

$database =& JFactory::getDBO(); 

//Declare Variables
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$id = $user->get('id');
$name = $user->get('name');

// Display quizzes
echo "</br>";
echo "Quizzes History for : " ;
echo "<b>";
echo $name;
echo "</b>";


echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

$database->setQuery('SELECT distinct qui.title AS name,' .
        ' ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(profiles.title) 
              FROM #__jquarks_users_profiles AS users_profiles
              LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_profiles AS profiles ON users_profiles.profile_id = profiles.id
              WHERE users_profiles.user_id = sessionWho.user_id ) AS profile, ' .
        ' ( SELECT sum(score)  
              FROM #__jquarks_quizzes_answersessions
              WHERE quizsession_id = quizSession.id
              AND status <> -1 ) AS score,' .
        ' ( SELECT count(distinct(question_id))
              FROM #__jquarks_quizzes_answersessions 
              WHERE quizsession_id = quizSession.id ) AS maxScore,' .

            ' ( SELECT count(id)
              FROM #__jquarks_quizzes_answersessions 
              WHERE status=-1
              AND quizsession_id = quizSession.id ) AS evaluate,' .
' quizSession.finished_on,sessionWho.email' .     
        ' FROM #__jquarks_quizsession AS quizSession' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_users_quizzes AS users_quizzes ON users_quizzes.id = quizSession.affected_id' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_quizzes AS qui ON users_quizzes.quiz_id = qui.id' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_quizzes_answersessions AS quizSessAns ON quizSessAns.quizsession_id = quizSession.id' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_sessionwho AS sessionWho ON sessionWho.session_id = quizSession.id' .
        ' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_users_profiles AS users_profiles ON users_profiles.user_id = sessionWho.user_id' .
' LEFT JOIN #__jquarks_profiles AS profiles ON profiles.id = users_profiles.profile_id '.

' WHERE sessionWho.user_id =' .$id) ;

if (!$database->query()) { //write data and if error occurs alert
    echo "<script> alert('".$database->getErrorMsg()."'); </script>";
}

//var_dump($database);
$tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; 
$tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 

echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="7">'; 
echo "<tr> <th> Quiz Title </th><th> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th> Unanswered </th> <th>Finished On </th></tr>"; 

$row = $database->loadRowList();
foreach($row as $valuearray)
{
echo '<tr style=" align="center">';
foreach($valuearray as $field)
{

echo "<td>$field</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Look into using [HEREDOCs](http://php.net/heredoc) for building those SQL queries. It'll save you the headaches of repeated string concatenation and allow you write it out 'nicely' with indenting.

Comment: dunno if it influenced on something but in this string "echo '<tr style=" align="center">';" you have style="(double-quote) not a style=''(two single quotes). i.e. this is generate invalid html(i'm sure browser will fix it)

Comment: wow, what a Query you have 4 subqueries and 6 joins, can you tell me what is performance of this? just wondering

Answer (score 2):

You have 5 `<th>` headers but select 6 columns from your table. Either explicitly print the fields from the table you want (you should), or change the query to only select the 5 you want.

Comment: I need the 6 fields can you show me how can increase my table to 6, and possibly separate the headers to match with the columns,,, ?

Comment: Write `<th>6th Field</th>` in the first row of the table where you want it to be. The headers will appear in the order you write them in the HTML.

Comment: the headers are now no inline with the output, how can give a static measure to the generated HTML

Comment: Instead of a loop `foreach($valuearray as $field)` write out the `echo '<td>' . $valuearray['fieldname'] . '</td>';` code in the order you want them displayed.

Comment: this {//var_dump($database);
 $tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px";
  $tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 
 echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="9">';  echo "<tr> <th> Quiz Title </th><th> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th> Unanswered </th> <th> Finished On </th> <th></th></tr>";   $row = $database->loadRowList(); 
foreach($row as $valuearray)
 { 
echo '<tr style=" align="center">'; 
echo '<td>' . $valuearray['score'] . '</td>';
 
echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>"; ?>}

Comment: code //var_dump($database);
 $tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px";
  $tdStyle = "padding:5px "; 
 echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="9">';  echo "<tr> <th> Quiz Title </th><th> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th> Unanswered </th> <th> Finished On </th> <th></th></tr>";   $row = $database->loadRowList(); 
foreach($row as $valuearray)
 { 
echo '<tr style=" align="center">'; 
echo '<td>' . $valuearray['score'] . '</td>';
 
echo "</tr>";
 }

 echo "</table>"; ?>

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to format the code..`code this {//var_dump($database); $tableStyle = "padding: 5px;border:1px"; $tdStyle = "padding:5px "; echo '<table style="' . $tableStyle . '" cellpadding="9" cellspacing="9">'; echo "<tr> <th> Quiz Title </th><th> Score </th><th>Maximum Score </th><th> Unanswered </th> <th> Finished On </th> <th></th></tr>"; $row = $database->loadRowList(); foreach($row as $valuearray) { echo '<tr style=" align="center">'; echo '<td>' . $valuearray['score'] . '</td>'; echo "</tr>"; } echo "</table>"; ?>} `code`